# ERROR 2013 MySQL server "system error: 104"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to connect to a remote Percona cluster over a load balancer.  The cluster **is** up.

Percona cluster version is 5.6.30-76.3-56, and mysql client version is Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-client-56-5.6.30-25.16.1

I've seen lots of questions regarding "system error: 0" and "system error: 54", but none regarding "system error: 104".

Here's what things look like on the **remote client**.  The fact that telnet to port 3306 works means that I don't think that it's a network/firewall issue.  There's no mysql log file on the client host, and nothing appears in /var/log/mysqld.log in any of the cluster members.

Bottom line: what is system error 104?

Thanks

```
$ mysql -u root --password=xxxxx -h 10.0.85.17
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 104

$ telnet 10.0.85.17 3306
Trying 10.0.85.17...
Connected to 10.0.85.17.
Escape character is '^]'.
telnet> quit

$ cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-links=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
connect_timeout=10
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

It was a routing error.  (No route back from the db servers over the load balancers to the host where I ran the mysql client.)

Comment: Am facing the same issue, can you let me know how to check this? Telnet connects so any other way to know that this is a routing issue?

Comment: No test that I know of.  Whenever we've gotten that error, though, it's turned out to be a routing issue across the LB.

Comment: I am having this issue right now, how did you resolve this?

Comment: The network team performed some configuration magic.  I never knew exactly what they did except to ensure that there was a "route back from the db servers over the load balancers to the host where I ran the mysql client".